# Move data from mysql to oracle with data contain html format use sql loader

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sql-loader

Please help move data from mysql to oracle with data contain html format use sqlloader.

I has export data mysql to file csv. 
sample data csv :

```
±14044±©±1±©±1±©±1±©±MailManager Attachment±©±image001.gif±©±6416-01-11 11:30:06±©±6416-01-11 11:30:06±©±null±©±null±©±0±©±1±©±0±©±null±
±14045±©±1±©±1±©±1±©±MailManager Attachment±©±image002.jpg±©±6416-01-11 11:30:06±©±6416-01-11 11:30:06±©±null±©±null±©±0±©±1±©±0±©±null±
±14046±©±1±©±1±©±1±©±Emails±©±"
                <p>"
                         </p>"
                <p style=""margin:0;padding:0;"">"
                        On 02-20-2014 13:26:49, crmtelesales@fecredit.com.vn, wrote:</p>"
                <blockquote style=""border:0;margin:0;border-left:1px solid #808080;padding:0 0 0 2px;"">"
                        <div style=""font-size:13px;font-family:tahoma;color:rgb(0,0,0);font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;background-image:none;background-attachment:scroll;background-position:0% 0%;"">"
                                do not reply</div>"
                        <br />"
                         </blockquote>"
                <br />±©±2014-03-03 10:11:39±©±2014-03-03 10:11:39±©±null±©±null±©±0±©±1±©±0±©±Re: tests±
```

My control file

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE '/home/ggt/csv/vtiger_crmentity.csv'
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE DWVTIGER.VTIGER_CRMENTITY
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," ENCLOSED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
( 
  CRMID        ,
  SMCREATORID  ,
  SMOWNERID    ,
  MODIFIEDBY   ,
  SETYPE       ,
  DESCRIPTION   NULLIF DESCRIPTION='null',
  CREATEDTIME   date "yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss" ,
  MODIFIEDTIME  date "yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss" ,
  VIEWEDTIME    date "yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss" NULLIF VIEWEDTIME='null',
  STATUS        NULLIF STATUS='null',
  VERSION       ,
  PRESENCE      NULLIF PRESENCE='null',
  DELETED       ,
  LABEL         NULLIF LABEL='null'
 )
```

Comment: data in html format , but when i post to that wesite it "  
" " On 02-20-2014 13:26:49, crmtelesales@console.com, wrote:

" " " do not reply"
"  "

Answer (score 0):

SQL*Loader cannot load data that is in HTML format.  You will need to get the data out of the page and make a true CSV before SQL Loader can load it.  It's made to load data in flat files, where each row is a record and each record is alike (basically).

You need to read up on this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_concepts.htm#g1013706
and this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_control_file.htm#i1006645